# GeoIP y htaccess | Añadir cookie y hacer una redirección por país

Tags: .htaccess, apache2, redirección

Estoy intentando hacer lo siguiente:

Dependiendo del país del que venga el visitante (el cual obtengo a través del `mod_geoip` de Apache) le pongo una `cookie` y le redirecciono a la `URL` destinada a él.

El problema es que me está creando redirecciones infinitas y por tanto un error de `ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS`

El código es el siguiente:

```
<IfModule mod_geoip.c>

    RewriteEngine on

    RewriteCond %{ENV:GEOIP_COUNTRY_CODE} ^(PT|GB)$ [NC]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} !lang=pt-gb [NC]
    RewriteRule .* "-" [CO=lang:pt-gb:.mydomain.es:7200:/] 
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://mydomain.es/en [R=301,L]

</IfModule>
```

El problema es que me crea infinitas redirecciones, pero si que me pone la `cookie` en la primera petición que es un 301. Por lo que pasa por todos `RewriteRule`.

Entiendo que una vez pone la `cookie` en la segunda condición:

```
RewriteRule .* "-" [CO=lang:pt-gb:.mydomain.es:7200:/]
```

En la segunda petición esto `RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} !lang=pt-gb [NC]` no debería de ser correcto y por tanto no redireccionar de nuevo, ya que por defecto las `RewriteCond` son `[AND]`, pero no consigo saber porqué me lo está haciendo.

Generalmente pruebo este tipo de cosas aquí: https://htaccess.madewithlove.be/ pero no soporta GeoIP

Después de leer la documentación de `mod_rewrite`, se supone que la primera parte `.*` de la colocación de la `cookie` es para definir una URL concreta (en este caso cualquiera) y la segunda para modificar la URL si queremos, de ahí el `"-"` no la quiero modificar porque la voy a redirigir más tarde.

Y con esto `RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} !lang=pt-gb [NC]` comprobamos si existe la `cookie` en el cliente.

He probado diferentes variantes de este código, pero ninguno me ha valido, también algunas respuestas de StackOverflow en ingles, pero lo mismo, ninguna me ha valido.

Creo que me estoy dejando algo y no se lo que es, ¿alguien que pueda arrojar algo de luz sobre este tema?

Si necesitáis que amplíe con más información unicamente pedidlo.

Muchas gracias por vuestro tiempo.

**Actualización:**

Al hilo de lo que han comentado abajo he probado lo siguiente:

```
RewriteCond %{ENV:GEOIP_COUNTRY_CODE} ^(PT|GB)$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} !^lang [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/en
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://mydomain/en [R=301,L]
```

Y más abajo:

```
RewriteRule .* "-" [CO=lang:%{ENV:GEOIP_COUNTRY_CODE}:.mydomain.es:7200:/]
```

Con esto debería de colocarse siempre la `cookie` después de la redireccion, pero me sigue haciendo un `loop`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La cookie que fijas con el flag [CO] nunca llega guardarse en el browser si la cabecera de respuesta indica una redirección (301, 302). El browser asume que las cookies relevantes se las entregará el sitio adonde está siendo redirigido. En otras palabras, tus reglas de redirección entran en un loop infinito porque la cookie nunca alcanza a fijarse.

Yo aplicaría la siguiente lógica:

- Si geoip me indica que el visitante viene de PT|GB, y no tiene la cookie, fijo la cookie.
- Acto seguido, redirijo cualquier url que no empiece con `/en` a tu subdirectorio `/en`

Esto es:

```
 RewriteCond %{ENV:GEOIP_COUNTRY_CODE} ^(PT|GB)$ [NC]
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} !lang=pt-gb [NC]
 RewriteRule .* "-" [CO=lang:pt-gb:.mydomain.es:7200:/]
 RewriteRule !^en http://mydomain.es/en [R=301,L]
```

Lo que ocurre acá es que en la primera visita la persona no recibe la cookie, sino que es redirigida a `http://mydomain.es/en`. Cuando cae en esa dirección, ya no será redirigido y ahora sí recibirá la cookie.

Ahora, me imagino que si estás fijando la cookie es para poder identificarlo de ahí en adelante aunque GeoIP ya no lo identifique como PT|GB. Entonces añades una segunda regla que diga: "si tiene la cookie, y no está visitando `http://mydomain.es/en` también lo redirijo:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} lang=pt-gb
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/en
RewriteRule !^en/.* /en/ [R,L]
```

Comment: En ambos casos (poniendo el código de la cookie antes o después de los `RewriteCond` que me has dacilitado, el resultado es el mismo: `ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS`. ¿Algo que pueda estar haciendo mal o que debiera de cambiar?

Comment: He actualizado la pregunta con alguna modificación más por si te vale.

Comment: Pero has probado no redirigir todo sino sólo lo que no empiece con `^en`? a mí me funcionó en mi local

Comment: Hola, perdona por contestar tan tarde. Sí, probé exactamente el mismo código que me has facilitado, y me sigue haciendo el loop.

Comment: En ese caso, un último workaround: sólo fija la cookie por Apache (me dices que eso ya está funcionando) y luego redirige ya sea en la capa de negocios o en el mismo frontend. Ojo que javascript sólo puede leer cookies que no hayan sido definidas como http only